# Mongo Ops Manager email alert

Tags: mongodb-mms

I'm using mongoDB Ops Manager 2.0.0.327 and i'm trying to
send alert by email.
I've configure all the needed parameters in to Ops Manager Config and opened port 25,
when I try to send test message (Control panel->send test message) but it does nothing (I dont know if the button just do nothing or there is an error)..
I also tried to add alert that send email to me, but i'm not getting email while I see that the alert triggered and "Sent mail".
How can I locate the error? Is there any log for this?

Thanks